# Tab completion: highight first different character / common part / uncommon part

Tags: bash

When working in directories with many similarly named files, I run into the following situation:

Say I have many files with a common prefix. If I hit tab after typing some part of the prefix, the common prefix will be completed, up onto the uncommon part. Additionally, the files that have this common prefix will be shown. However, in this list of files, it is hard to see what part corresponds to the common prefix, and what part does not. Hence, it is hard to know what to type next.

Concrete example: if I type `common-pre` it may be expanded to `common-prefix-` and the following files will be shown: `common-prefix-1234`, `common-prefix-0234`, `common-prefix-3234`, `common-prefix-5234`. In this case it's easy to see that the next thing to type is either a `0`, `1`, `3` or `5`. However, in practice the common prefix may be e.g. part of a date/time. For that scenario, highlighting either the common prefix or the uncommon part would be super-useful. In the example: **common-prefix-** 1234, **common-prefix-** 0234 etc.

Is it possible to get tab-completion configured like that in bash (or one of its competitors)?